# Dropbox iOS SDK "Broken"?```

Tags: ios, sdk, dropbox, dropbox-api

I am trying to use the latest official version of the DropBox iOS Core SDK, in particular the `DBRestClient`, to efficiently keep a document tree up to date on my local computer. However, several features of the SDK don't seem to be implemented as you'd expect, and I was wondering whether I am doing something wrong, failing to understand something, or on the other hand just looking for features that aren't there.

Dropbox has (at least?) two kinds of entities it stores: files and folders. If I make a change to a file in Dropbox, I can detect it by a change in the file's "rev" string.

However, for folders, the rev string doesn't change when the contents changes. For example, it doesn't change in response to any of the following:

1. Adding a file
2. Deleting a file
3. Editing a file

**Question 1:**
Is this the expected behavior ?  If so, does that mean that when I want to know if any of my Dropbox files have changed I must walk through the entire folder tree every time ?

**Deltas:**
There is a command to get a "delta" of the current contents (of something, the command takes no path parameters) related a "cursor" string.  The command looks like it is supposed to return a record of edited files/folders along with a new "cursor" string specifying the current state.  However, when I get the delta, the contents are always empty.  If I make a change in dropbox, and then send back the previous returned "cursor", I still get an empty delta.

**Question 2:**
Are deltas currently working in the SDK, and if so can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: Yes, that's the expected behavior. Typically you would use `delta` to watch for changes.

Question 2: Yes, I would assume that `delta` is working. You haven't shown any code, so it's impossible to guess what's going wrong.

Comment: Can I ask a followup question - I think this still falls under the scope of my original question - how can I tell if a file has been deleted ? When I add a file to a directory, or edit a file, I get a corresponding delta returned. But when I delete the new file, no delta is returned! Am I back to walking through the metadata ? In addition, I know this sounds quirky, but the contents of one subfolder in particular never show up in the delta. Have you found the performance of the SDK to be a bit flaky sometimes, or solid ?

Comment: You should get a delta entry for a delete. Per [the documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta), when you get back an entry with a path but no metadata, that means the file has been deleted. If you get back a deletion for a folder, you should consider all the files within that folder to be deleted.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I had not found more detailed documentation. Regarding the second issue of the subfolder, I found the cause - the file was being filtered out (by me) because it's metadata had a capitalization mistake: "docs/Other/testOther.txt", instead of "Docs/Other/testOther.txt". I see there is also a "lowercasePath" variable, to help with the quirky HFS+ (mis)use of mixed case paths. Actually, both issues were related to filtering - I was also filtering out the deleted paths because they had no metadata. Thank you for your help. Answer: the iOS SDK is not broken.